# How to make it so that I can't re-image my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, wipe

I'm running windows 7. How can I make it so that I (or anyone else) cannot re-image my computer. Is there software or drivers I should get to do this? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Actually, your solution is to lock your computer so people Don't change anything. Solve the root of the problem.

Comment: @Joao - When you edit a question people can reverse their upvote or downvote at that time.

Comment: @Sickest, locking a computer won't disable pranksters from booting a computer to network and then re-image it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is being booted to PXE / Network and then re-imaged as a prank, then you should change your Boot Device Sequence and lock your BIOS with a password.

This will disable the pranksters from booting into network and hence re-imaging your computer.